# Extremely small confidence intervals and standard deviations in a clmm-model

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, link-function

I have a data set with an effort rating (varying in an ordinal scale from 1 to 7) as the response variable and a time point of measure (seven consecutive measures) as a fixed factor. An individual is a random intercept in my model. My data set has 48 participants. I have modeled the data using the ordinal-package´s clmm-function. This is my model:

```
effMod <- ordinal::clmm(effort_rating ~ measure_time + (1|Var1), data=NASA_effcomcat)
```

Is there a problem when my standard errors as well as the confidence intervals are super small? Here are the results:

[image: model summary]

[image: confidence intervals]

Here is what my data looks like. There is a rating of each individual on different time points.

[image: data visualization]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar experience where the standard error was far, far smaller than what I obtained without random effects, and the result of `ordinal` did not at all match a Bayesian random effects ordinal model.  I concluded that the many approximations that are made in frequentist mixed effects models just don't work with this many random effects and this few subjects.

Bayesian random effects models are extremely easy to interpret and don't make approximations.

Random effects are not necessarily a well-fitting way to model within-person correlation.  See https://fharrell.com/post/re

Comment: Thanks, Frank! Initially, the ordinal scale was from 1 to 21, but as there would have been too few observations in each rating, I combined each three consecutive levels to get the scale from 1 to 7. What I found a bit surprising was that when I combined some levels of the ordinal scale differently, the standard errors seemed way more normal.

Comment: Since your model is assuming proportional odds (parallelism) it is not a good idea to combine levels and this should be totally unnecessary.  If the number of levels causes a problem with `ordinal` that is a problem with `ordinal`.  You can have thousands of levels with frequentist models using `rms::orm` (without random effects) or with Bayesian models using `rmsb::blrm` (with or without random effects).  You don't combine levels with the Wilcoxon test and the PO model is a generalization of Wilcoxon.